# How to add cascaded delete to Microsoft SQL Database

Tags: c#

On my website that is hosted on local machine I added a feature to be able to delete a profile I accomplished this by adding cascade delete to my local database However I am not sure how to do this on the database where my website is hosted. Does anyone know how to add cascaded delete to the tables in a Microsoft SQL Database hosted by 1and1.com?

Comment: can you run arbitrary SQL on the server?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? Do you mean sql queries?

Comment: So you added ON DELETE CASCADE  to the respective foreign keys?

Comment: Only on my local database I can't figure out how to add this to the one hosted on 1and1?

Comment: Do you have access to those databases?

Comment: yes. Maybe I will just try uploading the whole database again. Do you think this will take care of this?

Comment: Can't you just run the appropriate DDL on the remote instance?